How can I create a single time series chart with lines for each device category (mobile, desktop, tablet)?
I can't figure out how to map a single metric but filtered in a single time series chart. I want to see a single chart for Views, but different lines for mobile, desktop, and tablet users by day.
A filter affects the whole chart, and a calculated field doesn't seem to do anything. I tried making "Device - mobile (calculated)" by using:
REGEXP_MATCH(Device category, "mobile")
But that just broke my chart. I am not an admin in my organization so I have limited access to functions. Basically, I want these two charts to be one: two charts - desktop views & mobile views
ETA: Using "Device Category" doesn't do what I want. It presents as a single line for views by day. not working: time series chart with device category

You should use Device Category as a breakdown dimension in your chart.

Device Category presents as a single line for users by day. That's not it.


You want to see something like this right?
Device Category as a breakdown dimension is right.
From the screenshot you show. You place the Device Category as metric so it shows a line. It should put in breakdown dimension:


Yes, that's exactly it! Thank you!!!!
